# Vue.JS/Vuetify - Making v-list using data returned from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch, vuetify.js, spotify

I am working on a project trying to display data from Spotify's API.  I have created a v-list using an array of data that is returned as follows:

```
      <v-col class="d-flex justify-start"
              cols="12"
              sm="4">
        <v-card>
        <h3> The genres are: </h3>
        <p> Double click to launch recommendations </p>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedGenre">    
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(items, i) in items.genres"
            :key="i"
            :value="items"
            @click="updateSelectedGenre(selectedGenre)"
            >
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="items"
              :value="items"
              ></v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
```

Then response data that is returned from spotify is an array of objects, of arrays, or more objects.  I successfully was able to just list out the top ten results of the api call above using the following code:

```
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[0].artists[0].name }} </tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[1].artists[0].name }} </tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[2].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[3].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[4].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[5].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[6].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[7].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[8].artists[0].name }}</tr>
          <tr>{{ topTenRecs.tracks[9].artists[0].name }}</tr>
```

I am trying to make it so that when you click on the recommended artist it will v-model this artist name so that I can use it in a new API call, but have not been able to figure out how to do this yet.

So far I have it as follows, but it is not working yet :(

```
        <v-list-item-group v-model="selectedArtist">   
          <v-list-item 
          v-for="(recommendation, i) in topTenRecs.tracks" :key="i">
            {{ recommendation.topTenRecs }}
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
```

The spotify API call that I am making is: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-recommendations/?limit=10&market=&seed_artists=&seed_genres=acoustic

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Sure, good call.  I am trying to get one set up right now :)

Comment: Here is the codesandbox that I have set up so far, but I haven't been able to get the API calls working in this.  
https://codesandbox.io/s/spotify-app-vuetify-j2iq5